# direct page access prevention

Tags: php, security, authentication

on my site i have 2 pages, a simple password protected page called `login.php` and the main webpage called `index.php`

I am trying to prevent users from directly accessing 'index.php'

1. If a visitor tried to access `index.php` directly, it would redirect to `login.php`
2. If the visitor entered the correct password, it would allow access to the `index.php` file.

Currently, I'm stuck in a loop.

1. When i try to access `index.php` directly, i am redirected to `login.php` - this is ok
2. When i enter the password, click enter, I'm sent to `index.php` then looped back to the `login.php' page

how do prevent this loop please

```
// index.php
<?php
    if (!isset($include_allowed)){
        die("<meta http-equiv='refresh'content='0;url=\"http://www.myweb.com/login.php'>");
    }
?>
```

-

```
// login.php
<?php
    $include_allowed = true;
?>
```

many thanks (sorry if its confusing)

please note, there is no username, just a basic password form that checks the password matches the variable before sending to the 'index.php' page

```
if ($pass == "mypassword") {
```

Comment: You need [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of tutorials on the web about setting up an authentication system for your website. What you are looking for is using `sessions`.

Heres a good article on it: http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/user-authentication/Jason_Gilmore05172011.php3

basically, from here (having the login page), you'd want to have something like

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'isLogged' ] ) ) {
    header( 'Location: login.php' );
}
```

in your `index.php`

More Links:

http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/101-274721/good-tutorial-for-authenticated-web-sessions-using-phpmysql

http://www.slideshare.net/chadhutchins/basic-user-authentication-with-php-mysql

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/php-login-page-example.html

**EDIT:**

You can also take a look at: [Http Authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php), if you want to avoid using sessions. This can actually also get rid of your `login.php` script

Comment: the slideshare one is actually where id start

Comment: many thanks, tutorial  was great, had to make a few minor changes to the website, but nothing major. All working perfectly now :-)